# cor() with missing values

Tags: r, loops, correlation, missing-data

I want a matrix with only the correlation coefficients which are bigger than 0.2. I came up with the following solution.

```
mts.data <- ts(data.frame(a=arima.sim(model=list(1,0,0), n=10), 
      b=arima.sim(model=list(1,0,1), n=10), c=arima.sim(model=list(1,0,0), 
      n=10), d=arima.sim(model=list(1,0,2), n=10),
      e=arima.sim(model=list(2,0,1), n=10)), start=c(2007,1), frequency=12)

critcor <- function(x) {
  crit.mat <- matrix(0, nrow=ncol(x), ncol=ncol(x))
  for(j in 1:ncol(x)) {
    for(i in 1:ncol(x)) {
      if(abs(cor(x[,i], x[,j])) > 0.2) {
        crit.mat[i,j] <- cor(x[,i], x[,j])
      }
    }
  }
  return(crit.mat)
}
```

This works fine. Unfortunately, my data set contains missing values.

```
mts.data[1:3, 4] <- NA
mts.data[9:10, 5] <- NA
```

When I run my function, I got an error.

```
critcor(mts.data)
# Error in if (abs(cor(x[, i], x[, j])) > 0.2) { : 
#   missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I'm browsing the Internet for several hours now and I have absolutely no idea how I could fix this. If a correlation is not possible because of the missing values, I want my function just print a 0 instead.

Comment: See the argument `use` of the `cor` function. You should use either `complete.obs` or `pairwise.complete.obs` (probably the latter).

Comment: Indeed.. (as @mts) also does (via `"p"`) below.  @nelakell:  It will help you to get into the habit of reading R help pages, in this case  `?cor`. It would have directly told you that missing values can be handled very well.

Comment: Thank you @MartinMächler . That's a good advice. I was so into solving the problem of my function, that I haven't thought of that in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can greatly simplify your code like this:

```
cm = cor(mts.data, use = "p")
cm[abs(cm) <= 0.2] = 0
```

which gives:

```
> cm
           a          b          c          d          e
a  1.0000000  0.0000000 -0.4667718 -0.5241904 -0.6864418
b  0.0000000  1.0000000  0.0000000 -0.3270387  0.0000000
c -0.4667718  0.0000000  1.0000000  0.4708803  0.5222566
d -0.5241904 -0.3270387  0.4708803  1.0000000  0.0000000
e -0.6864418  0.0000000  0.5222566  0.0000000  1.0000000
```

The snippet `use = "p"` is short for "pairwise complete observations", i.e. `NA`s will be omitted when necessary. For more options and details see `?cor`.

The error you received was when you had a value that was `NA`. Then also the comparison `NA > 0.2` will be `NA` and `if` does not accept `NA` as its input, thus the error.